# Search using Or PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I am hoping this is a quick and easy question but I have not been able to find an answer. I am using the following code to search for a string in a word document:

```
$SearchString = "Some Text"
$regex = [Regex]::Match($PgContent.Text, $SearchString)
```

Which works great. But after error checking I found a few files that had a one off. So I need to be able to search using an OR. For instance:

```
$SearchString = "Some Text" OR "Different text"
$regex = [Regex]::Match($PgContent.Text, $SearchString)
```

If I could search for two terms and either term is on the page then save that page as my code does. Do I need to create two searchstrings? If so how do I implement to judge success off of finding either one?

Comment: `"Some Text|Different text"` - `|` pipe character is an either/or separator in regex language.

Comment: BTW you can use `-matches`: `if ($mytext -match 'door|window') { echo $matches }`

Comment: Thanks so much! Frustrating that I couldn't find that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using regex, you can use the pipe operator:

```
$SearchString = 'Some Text|Different text'
```